# Filter minimize event

Tags: c++, qt, mdi, qevent

I have a `QMdiSubWindow` and I need to filter the minimize event so that I can simply `hide()` the window.

I have tried the following:

```
void accounts::changeEvent ( QEvent *event )
{
     if(event->QEvent::WindowStateChange) {
          event->ignore(); 
     }
}
```

This filters ALL window state changes, such as maximize. I need the minimize event exclusively.

`event->ignore()` doesn't ignore anything. I also tried `event->setAccepted(false)`, which was also unsuccessful at cancelling out events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void accounts::event(QEvent *e)
{
  if (e->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange) {
    if (isMinimized()) {
      hide();
      e->ignore();
    } else {
      e->accept();
    }
  }
  QMdiSubWindow::event(e);
}
```